# Why maximum a posterior, not maximum posterior?

Tags: bayesian, maximum-likelihood, terminology, map-estimation

Is the additional "a" mean that different priors may lead to different posterior, MAP is a result of many possible results?  And similar to MLE, why the abbreviation of maximum a posterior estimation is MAP, not MPE or MAPE? Thanks

Comment: Note that "MPE" usually refers to the Mean Percentage Error, and [tag:mape] to the Mean Absolute Percentage Error.

Answer (score 13):

The phrase *a posteriori* is from Latin, the sort of Latin phrase that used to appear in educated British English.  Along with *a priori*, it was already in use in philosophy/logic in a slightly different sense before it got used in statistics.  There's not really any significance to the *a*, just history.

Comment: +1. [Here is Wikipedia on *a priori* and *a posteriori*.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_priori_and_a_posteriori)